# Why my custom AuthorizationHandler is executed twice with an AuthorizationFilterContextSealed object as context.Resource?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, .net-6.0, asp.net-authorization

I have developed an OData endpoint in .NET 6.0 and I need to add a custom parameterized Authorization filter.
Thanks to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0), I created customs *AuthorizeAttribute*, *IAuthorizationPolicyProvider* and *AuthorizationHandler* with its requirement.
The problem is that *HandleRequirementAsync* function is called three times when I execute a request:

- First time with a *DefaultHttpContext* object as *context.Resource*
- Two others times with an *AuthorizationFilterContextSealed* object as *context.Resource*

I didn't found a lot of information about this *AuthorizationFilterContextSealed* class...

Does someone know why these calls are done?

Is there a way to avoid them? Otherwise, what is the best practice to manage them? Because I cannot cast *context.Resource* as *AuthorizationFilterContextSealed* since this class is internal.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find out what's going on?

Comment: No I didn't get answer to what's going on sorry..

Comment: In my case, the problem was that in Program.cs I was adding my custom AuthorizationHandler with `builder.Services.AddAuthorization` but I had also a `builder.Services.AddMVC` statement adding another authorization policy with an AuthorizeFilter. That part was leftover boiler plate code that I didn't really need. So I removed the whole "AddMVC" call and now my handler is called only once and with the proper context. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Youlounn, were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: @thanzeel I wrapped HandleRequirementAsync whole code with: if (context.Resource is DefaultHttpContext)